# Tranforming Guava Optional with function that might return null

Tags: java, guava, option-type

### TL;DR

What is the best (i.e. most compact/readable) way of `transform`ing a Guava `Optional`, using a function that might return `null`? (So that in that case, we should get an `Optional.absent()`, instead of an NPE.)

Bonus question: is there an advantage, in the Guava way, namely to throw `NPE`, if the transformer function returns `null`? (Instead of converting it to `Optional.absent()`, like in case of Java 8 `Optional`s.) Or is it just a shortcoming of the design?

### Problem

As per the [documentation of Guava Optional.transform](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#transform(com.google.common.base.Function)):

> **Comparison to java.util.Optional**: this method is similar to Java 8's
>   `Optional.map`, except when function returns `null`. In this case this
>   method throws an exception, whereas the Java 8 method returns
>   `Optional.absent()`.

### Example

The following function is common to both examples:

```
public String methodThatMighReturnNull(boolean returnNull, Integer input) {
    return returnNull ? null : String.valueOf(input);
}
```

With **Java 8** this does not throw an NPE, but returns an empty `Optional`:

```
Optional<Integer> input = Optional.of(42);
Optional<String> result = input.map(new Function<Integer, String>() {
    public String apply(Integer input) {
        return methodThatMighReturnNull(true, input);
    }
});
```

The following, similar code with **Guava** throws an NPE:

```
Optional<Integer> input = Optional.of(42);
Optional<String> result = input.transform(new Function<Integer, String>() {
    public String apply(Integer input) {
        return methodThatMighReturnNull(true, input);
    }
});
```

### Possible alternatives

I have found/considered some alternatives, but, as described below, all are problematic:

1. Wrap the return value into an `Optional`. Problem: too cumbersome, more difficult to read;

   ```
   Optional<Integer> input = Optional.of(42);
   Optional<String> result = input.transform(new Function<Integer, Optional<String>>() {
       public Optional<String> apply(Integer input) {
           return fromNullable(methodThatMighReturnNull(true, input));
       }
   }).get();
   ```
2. Use `if/else`, by checking `ifPresent`. Problem: kind of kills the point of `Optional`. (We could just use the reference and check against `null` instead.)

   ```
   Optional<Integer> input = Optional.of(42);
   Optional<String> result;
   if (input.isPresent()) {
       result = fromNullable(methodThatMighReturnNull(true, input.get()));
   } else {
       result = Optional.absent();
   }
   ```
3. Just applying the function, and wrapping it in `fromNullable`. (As found on [GitHub](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1171#issuecomment-61349451), where the same problem was seemingly already brought up.) Problem: this is slightly different, than the original example. In this case, `methodThatMighReturnNull` could end up receiving `null`, while in the original case this was impossible.

   ```
   Optional<Integer> input = Optional.of(42);
   Optional<String> result;
   result = fromNullable(new Function<Integer, String>() {
       public String apply(Integer input) {
           return methodThatMighReturnNull(true, input);
       }
   }.apply(input.orNull()));
   ```

Comment: Is the Guava code in Java 8+? Lambdas would make #1 and #3 more palatable.

Comment: A more functional approach is to use `flatMap()` to ensure that you always map to the proper range.

Comment: Which version of Java is this?

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the alternatives you listed in your question, here are two other possibilities:

1. If you are on Java 8 or higher, starting from Guava 21.0, you have the [`Optional.toJavaUtil()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.6-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#toJavaUtil--) instance method, which transforms your Guava `Optional` instance into a [`java.util.Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) one, and also the [`Optional.fromJavaUtil`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.6-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#fromJavaUtil-java.util.Optional-) static method, which creates a Guava `Optional` instance from a `java.util.Optional` one.

   You can use them to let `java.util.Optional` take a function that invokes your method in its [`Optional.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method, applying its own semantics (it won't throw `NullPointerException` if the function returns `null`, but an empty `java.util.Optional` instead). Then, if you need it, convert this mapped `java.util.Optional` back to a Guava `Optional` via the `Optional.fromJavaUtil` method.

   Here's the code that shows this approach:

   ```
   Optional<Integer> input = Optional.of(42);
   java.util.Optional<String> temp = input.toJavaUtil()
       .map(i -> methodThatMighReturnNull(true, i));
   Optional<String> result = Optional.fromJavaUtil(temp);
   ```
2. If you are not in Java 8 or higher yet (or if you are but don't like the previous approach), I would go for a variant of your 2nd alternative. For this, I would implement a `transformNullSafe` method with the semantics you need:

   ```
   public static <T, R> Optional<R> transformNullSafe(
           Optional<T> optional,
           Function<T, R> function) {

       if (optional.isPresent()) {
           return Optional.fromNullable(function.apply(optional.get()));
       } else {
           return Optional.absent();
       }
   }
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   Optional<Integer> input = Optional.of(42);
   Optional<String> result = transformNullSafe(
       input, 
       new Function<Integer, String>() {
           public String apply(Integer i) {
               return methodThatMighReturnNull(true, i);
           }
       });
   ```

Comment: Thanks especially for pointing me to `toJavaUtil()`. I was not aware of its existence.